# Static objects becomes null when app brought back after being in background for long time

Tags: java, android

I am a very ad-hoc issue in my app. When my app stays in the background for a long time then sometime when I start it then app crashes, the log cat shows `NullPointerException` which is thrown by user object which I set as a static variable of a particular class.

Let me explain in a bit detail:

I have an Application class which contains a static variable name user which I set on successful login or when the app starts by reading login data in the device.

So when the user uses my app and forgets to close it and start using another app. When the user again start my app let's say after 2 days (user never closed app so far) it crashes. The issue is null pointer exception on Application class's static variable user. How can we handle this situation?

My app works fine when the app is restarted after being crashed.

Comment: "user never closed app so far" but Android does. It's better to use Shared Preference to store whatever value and retrieve the same when your application class is invoked.

Comment: you can use static final variables, although I suggest you to use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest to put the login information in the `SharedPreference` and then read the login data from preference inside your `onResume` function. This way the application will fetch the data from `SharedPreference` each time and the value stored in `SharedPreference` is saved.

However, you should not lose your static value if the app is not closed. I would suggest checking if there is any other life-cycle method (e.g. `onDestroy`) where you have assigned the value `null` in your static variable which might raise the problem.

Comment: No there is none.

Answer (score 1):

We could go on and on as to why it is happening, but instead of that I recommend you start using good practices. First of, you should generally avoid storing any data in your activities/fragments, because you have no guarantee as to when they will be recreated. Use ViewModel for that: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.
As to you particular problem, user preferences/temporary data should be stored in SharedPreferences, but you should create some kind of Service or some other layer and do not call this directly in your activities/fragments. Example:

```
public class PreferencesService {

    private static final String USER_NAME_KEY = "username";
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public PreferencesService(Context context) {
        preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public void writeUsername(String username) {
        preferences.edit().putString(USER_NAME_KEY, 
        username).apply();
    }

    public String readUsername() {
       return preferences.getString(USER_NAME_KEY, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The system may clear the memory reserved for the variables when the app is backgrounded and I suggest using saveInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable(TAG_FOR_BUNDLE, objectToSave);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        objectToSave = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(TAG_FOR_BUNDLE);
    }
}
```